# how to dynamic add <div> on html and write php inside html

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to use php to get Image file information in folder,and dynamic add image in div then add 
 into web page,below is my code,but it does not work, please help me.

**index.html**

```
<div class="scrollContainer">   
  <?php
    var $i = 1;
    var $panel_id = "panel_";
    var $imgUrl = "./Img/";
    var $file=NULL;

    var $dir = opendir("Img");
    while( ($file = readdir($dir)) !== false ){
      $panel_id = $panel_id.$i;
      $imgUrl = $imgUrl.$file;
      echo "$('.scrollContainer').html("
          ."$('<div/>')"
          .".addClass('panel')"
          .".id(".$panel_id.")"
          .".append("
          ."$('<div/>')"
          .".addClass('inside')"
          .".append("
          ."$('<img/>')"
          .".attr('src',".$imgUrl.")"
          .")"
          .".append("
          ."$('<p/>')"
          .".text(".$file.")"
          .")"
          .")"
          .");";

      $panel_id = "panel_";
      $imgUrl = "./Img/";
      $i = $i + 1;
    } // while

    closedir( $dir );
  ?> 
<div>
```

I am new hand, please help me , I appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have a MIME type saying .html files can run PHP? If not, change your file from `index.html` to `index.php`

Comment: Based on your syntax and programming style I guess you're confusing php and javascript a lot. Php doesn't complain, but I guess it would do you good to completely seperate the two and not make a mess of your code.

Comment: where are your <script> tags?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're doing it in this way? Why not just use php to output the images?

Comment: thanks everyone for help,I have change my file to `index.php` , I have also learned to mix write php and html.I create `<?php function dynamicAddDiv(){} ?>` then call this function in `<div class="scrollContainer">` this tag, and it succes now.

Answer (score 0):

You are combinate PHP with jquery create objects method???

You from PHP can write html code directly (I recomend a template sistaxis):

```
  <?php
    var $i = 1;
    var $panel_id = "panel_";
    var $imgUrl = "./Img/";
    var $file=NULL;

    var $dir = opendir("Img");

    ?>



    <div class="scrollContainer">

    <?php while( ($file = readdir($dir)) !== false ) : ?>

         <div src="panel" id="<?= $panel_id.$i ?>">
              <div class="inside">
                  <img src="img/<?= $imgUrl.$file ?>" />
                  <p><?= htmlentities($file) ?></p>
              </div>
         </div>  
      <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php
  closedir( $dir );
  ?> 
  </div>
```